# Check available diskspace in Bash Script and run command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the disk space available to do some commands afterwards.
Unfortunately somehow within the bash-script, I can't write the amount of bytes in a variable to do a while loop when it is checking if there is still some space left to write the data.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail
shopt -s nullglob globstar 

DISK_ROOTS=("/mnt/nfs1")

for index in "${!DISK_ROOTS[@]}"; do

        DISK_ROOT="${DISK_ROOTS[index]}"
        available_diskspace= 'df $DISK_ROOT | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}''   ##LINE 34
        echo "=== $available_diskspace BYTES Available ==== "
        while [ $available_diskspace -gt 5000000 ]
```

This is the error I get but I'm able to get the size when it is not in the script (?):

```
x@x:~$ ./v3.sh
./v3.sh: line 34: $4: unbound variable

x@x:~$ df /mnt/nfs1 | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
203897600
```

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Use `$(...)` to assign the output of a command to variable, not single quotes.

Comment: And you can't have a space after the `=` when assigning a variable.

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to check your script syntax.

Comment: Thanks bro! Putting the variable of the disk also in quotes... how did I miss this :) 
```available_diskspace=$(df "$DISK_ROOT"| awk 'NR==2 {print $4}')```